# Interpretation of covariant derivative of metric tensor being zero, specific problem on sphere

Tags: metric-tensor, differentiation

A question about the covariant derivative of the metric tensor being zero, example: sphere.

I understand, that the metric tensor of a (unit-)sphere is calculated via the outer product of the base vectors. Doing that, we get the tensor $g_{rr}=1$, $g_{\vartheta\vartheta}=\sin^2\vartheta$ (can show it if necessary, if I ever remember how to get that LaTeX tool invoked here)

I also understand, that the covariant derivative of the metric tensor equals zero (can prove it mathematically), and I read, that the intuitive interpretation of that is, that the metric does not change when we move on the sphere.

But the metric above definitely changes, since it contains $\sin^2\vartheta$ -- except if we move on a geodesic curve. But I thought, that a non-changing metric means it does not change in whatever direction we move.
Am I wrong there?

Comment: To use mathjax, wrap the relevant text with dollar signs (i.e., `$x^2$` yields $x^2$). Two consecutive dollar signs yields a centered equation. See [Help::notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for more details

Comment: In short: the components of the metric may change depending on the coordinate system you are using, but this is not physical. The fact that $\nabla_\mu g_{\rho\sigma}=0$ is the tensorial formulation of the metric being constant which then holds for all coordinate systems. When you look at the metric in $\mathbb R^2$ using polar coordinates its components are changing as well but we know that this just an effect of the coordinates being used. The metric is flat.

Comment: Thanks, Kurt, I added a follow-up question, but it ended up at the bottom (please, scroll all the way down)

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, I want to clear out some misconceptions. The value of $\nabla_{\mu}g_{\rho \sigma}$ depends on your choice of *connection*. The reason why in curved spaces $\nabla_{\mu} \neq \partial_{\mu}$ is because the basis which we use to expand the vectors change from point to point. Note that this is not what we observe in flat Euclidean space. The basis vectors are the same everywhere. Mathematically speaking, the basis vectors (and therefore the vectors themselves) live in different tangent spaces. This is a fancy way of saying that not only the value of the component changes, your basis vectors are changing as you move around in your curved space.

This is where the connection comes to play. The connection tells you how the basis vectors change from point to point. Then, you use this to define the full covariant derivative which tells the change in the value of the vector $\textbf{and}$ the basis components. This is why it is misleading to say that the metric in question changes as we vary $\theta$ and therefore it is not constant. You are forgetting to account for the change in the basis! If you also account for the change in basis (via christoffel symbols), you can see that the metric won't change.

Now I also want to address the claim I made at the beginning where I said that the covariant derivative of the metric depends on the connection you choose. This will contain some mathematical jargon so you can skip to the end where I give the physical usefulness of the connection used in General Relativity. You can read more about it from Harvey Reall's lecture note on General Relativity. Generally, covariant derivatives are defined before we even talk about connection. These objects are defined such that they obey some fundamental properties (such as linearity, Leibniz Rule etc.). This definition does not single out a preferred connection (i.e an object that tells you how the basis vectors change). However, it turns out (this can be proved easily) that there exists a *unique* symmetric connection such that $\nabla g = 0$. This is called the Levi-civita connection and the main connection we use in General Relativity. The fact that it is covariantly conserved implies that the metric doesn't change depending on where we are in the manifold and therefore assign distances quite nicely everywhere in the space. Furthermore, Levi-Civita connection arises naturally when we consider Lagrangians which is a nice sign as Lagrangians have been a very good framework to write our theories in.

Comment: Thanks, Kurt and Emir,

Comment: Follow-up questionto Kurt: Spherical polar coordinates in flat space: Metric is not constant because of "wrong": coordinate system --  got it. But then there should be a system of base vectors on the sphere, where the metric is obviously constant, meaning,  does not depend on vartheta nor varphi. What coo-transform do I need no make?

Comment: Thanks, Kyle, now I remember how to format math text.

Comment: Follow-follow up: or is it not possible to find such a system of base vectors which create a metric that does not depend on $\vartheta$ because I am moving from one tangential plane to  the next while moving?  In what coordinates on a sphere can I see the metric being constant? Or am I totally off?

Comment: you can create a coordinate basis where the metric is that of minkowski. This is called a tetrad basis and in this coordinate basis you import all the geometry to your basis vectors.

Comment: @Fuzzy it is impossible to find coordinate systems on the sphere (if that’s really what you mean…) in which the metric components are constant. The sphere is curved, and one of the fundamental theorems of Riemannian geometry tells us of this impossibility. Given any (pseudo) Riemannian manifold, you can always find a local orthonormal frame: simply take any local frame (eg a coordinate-induced frame), and perform the linear algebra Gram-Schmidt procedure. **Warning**: the resulting orthonormal frame need not come from a coordinate system (and usually it wont).

Comment: ok, peek-a-boo, I get it: an orthonormal base system with a constant metric is only possible locally, and it changes from position to position, as the space curves. And with the base vectors the metric changes (or not?). So, why is the covariant derivative of that (changing!) metric equal to zero? Is that the result of the connection coefficients we created from that metric?  If you can agree to that, I think, my problem is solved!. --- Emir: A tetrad basis is also a basis only locally, or?

Comment: I think my comment may have caused a confusion. A tetrad basis is not a coordinate basis but a globally orthonormal basis. For example, in our case, defining $e^1 = d\theta$ and $e^2 = sin(\theta) d\phi$ allows us to write the metric as $g = (e^1)^2 + (e^2)^2$. Clearly in this basis the metric is kronecker delta and defined everywhere.

Comment: One addendum: when I say this coordinate is defined everywhere; I mean it is defined everywhere on the chart we are using. There is a coordinate singularity at $\theta = 0, \pi$ but we inherit this from the coordinates we are using; not from the tetrads itself.

Comment: Is it not $d\varphi^2+\sin^2\vartheta d\vartheta^2$? And why should there be a singularity? Even at $\vartheta=0$ and $\vartheta=\pi$ everything is defined. Or am I  misunderstanding you?

Comment: I mean the actual notation doesn't matter. There is a singularity in the sense that the metric is not well defined at those points since it is not invertible there. However, this is not something physical; just an artefact of the charts we are using.

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, anyway, thanks a lot - I think I need an eye full of sleep now.